# Regular Expression Stopping at Specified Value

Tags: regex

I have to use a regular expression to parse values out of a swift message and there are some situations where the behaviour is not what I want.

Lets say I am after something with a particular pattern - in this case a BIC (6 letters, followed by 2 letters or digits followed by optional `XXX` or 3 digits)

```
([A-Z]{6}[A-Z0-9]{2}[XXX0-9]{0,3})
```

this is fine but now I want to look for these bank codes in particular fields. In swift a field is denoted with `:` and has some numbers and sometimes a letter.

so I want to match a BIC value in field `52A`

I can do the following

```
(52A:[A-Z]{6}[A-Z0-9]{2}[XXX0-9]{0,3})
```

which would match `52A:AAAAAAAAXXX`

my problem is you can have things before and after this value - and the value itself might not exist in the field you want

so I can wildcard the reg ex to allow for things before it for example

```
(52A:.*?[A-Z]{6}[A-Z0-9]{2}[XXX0-9]{0,3})
```

matches `52A:somerubbishAAAAAAAAXXX`

but if there isnt something within this field - the reg ex continues to search for the pattern and this is where i have a problem.

for example the above reg ex matches this `52A:somerubbish:57D:AAAAAAAAXXX`

**Question**

I need the reg ex to stop on the first field that is after it (it might not always be `57D` but it will always follow the format `[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{0,1})`
so the above example shouldnt return a match as the pattern I am after is not contained in the `52A` section

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: `[XXX0-9]{0,3}` translates to "1, 2, or 3 capital Xs or digits in any combination".

Comment: Yes it an optional branch code

Comment: So the branch code can be "X8X"?

Comment: @JamesCooke So branch code can be simply `X2`?

Comment: Actually I think the branch code is either nothing (it's optional) xxx or some kind of 3 digit number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `.*?` to `[^:]*?`:

```
(52A:[^:]*?[A-Z]{6}[A-Z0-9]{2}[XXX0-9]{0,3})
```

`[^:]` means "any character except :", which ensures the match doesn't run into the next field.

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/wK5evDWKRtFRDp).

Also, unless your situation requires you to match your target as group 1, you don't need the outer brackets: the entire match (ie group 0) will be your target.

---

I suspect instead of `[XXX0-9]{0,3}` you want `(XXX|\d{3})?` (XXX or 3 digits, but optionally) or perhaps `(XXX|\d{1,3})?` (XXX or up to 3 digits, but optionally)

Answer (score 0):

Using `[XXX0-9]{0,3}` (which is the same as `[X0-9]{0,3}`) is a character class notation, repeating 0-3 times an X char or a digit.

If the value itself can also contain a colon, you can match any character as "rubbish" as long as what is directly to the right is not the field format.

```
52A:(?:(?![0-9]{2}[A-Z]?:).)*[A-Z]{6}[A-Z0-9]{2}(?:[0-9]{3}|XXX)?
```

The pattern matches:

- `52A:` Match literally
- `(?:(?![0-9]{2}[A-Z]?:).)*` Match any character asserting not 2 digits, optional char A-Z and : directly to the right
- `[A-Z]{6}[A-Z0-9]{2}` Match 6 chars A-Z and 2 chars A-Z or 0-9
- `(?:[0-9]{3}|XXX)?` Optionally match 3 digits or XXX

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FJdccb/1).